# javascript : window.location.href/window.open is not working on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, html

**Updated Code**

```
<div>
    <button type="button" class="submit btn btn-default" id="btnSubmit">Submit 
    </button>
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>




<script>
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e)
 {
  e.preventDefault();

  //btn Click validation and code submission goes here..

   alert("Form has been successfully submitted");
   window.open("http://....../viewmyrequest.aspx","_self"); 

  }

</script>
```

**window.location.href** is working only on debug mode and redirect to other window is not happening if i turned off debug mode.

i have explored many StackOverflow questions with the same topic but i haven't got any solid response for this issue.

```
window.location.href = "http://testwebsite.com/viewtickets.aspx"
```

i have tried for other options too

```
window.location = "http://testwebsite.com/viewtickets.aspx"
window.location.replace = "http://testwebsite.com/viewtickets.aspx"
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: window.location redirection is not working

Comment: Okay so what triggers that code to run?

Comment: Button Click on a iframe.

Comment: What is the button html look like?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Works cross browser in all my sites.

```
loc = "http://testwebsite.com/viewtickets.aspx";
    window.open(loc,'_self');
```

EDITED:
This may work better for you..

```
<script>
function setURL(url){
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
}
</script>
<iframe id="iframe" src="idreesinc.com/research.html" />
<input type="button" onclick="setURL('URLHere')" />
```

It will insert the correct URL into the iframe.

Comment: i have tried your suggestion but still not working without enabling debug mode.

Comment: i forgot to inform you i am doing this button click which trigger window.open on a iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I am 99% sure the issue is you are using a submit button and that is submitting the form which is not allowing your JavaScript to run. So either you need to set the type to be a button and not a submit button OR you need to cancel the click action.

```
<button type="button" ... >
```

or

```
<button onclick="foo(); return false;" ... >
```

Comment: Thanks @epascarello. I have changed from "submit" to "button". But still it is not working when debug mode is off.

Comment: If i click the button second time, it works. not sure whats going wrong

Comment: I have updated my question with the code. thanks for your help in advance.